# Can i avoid showing all tenant developer portal in wso2 API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-cloud

I am using WSO2 API Manager .In developer portal there is options to switch through multiple tenant's developer portal But I need to avoid the list of developer portals and user must be directed to single tenant's developer portal even if they are users of another tenant .Is it possible to do so?
[image]
I need to show onlycarbon.super or completely avoid this page and only allow users from test1 and test2 tenant to login to carbon.super developer portal.

Comment: Can you share the API Manager version?

Comment: API Manager 4.0.0

Comment: As out-of-the-box, there isn't any configuration to route all requests to the `carbon.super` tenant's portal. I believe that your requirement is that even though you have multiple tenants, all APIs are going to be created and published under only the `carbon.super` tenant and please correct if my understanding is wrong. You can remove that Tenant Listing page by doing few modifications to the React App, but this needs a thorough testing.

Comment: Yeah , All APIs will be created and published under only carbon.super
I had tried changing the active to false in publicTenantStore option in react,But I hae confusion on what should be the redirectTiIfInActive  uri to make it directed towards carbon.super devportal

Comment: We can use that configuration to redirect the Devportal to some other URLs. Since, you are trying to display only the `carbon.super` tenant in the Devportal, I am not quite sure whether that will work as expected and will cause a loop of redirection. As alternate way, you can enhancing the TenantListing.jsx to route to `carbon.super` tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any out-of-the-box configurations to disable that view (other than Redirection configuration) and route all to the `carbon.super` tenant in the API Manager. Therefore, to remove that view from the Devportal, you may need to do some advanced customization in the Devportal React application.

You can try checking the source of `TenantListing.jsx` under the `Devportal` react application for more clarification and make relevant changes to disable the view and route all traffic to the `carbon.super` tenant's portal.